# How to fix overlapping shadows of two objects?

Tags: mesh

I created two cubes, and shadows appear at the overlapping part of them.
Even if I remove the light, it still appears. What should I do?
[image]

Comment: Hello, are you sure that this is a python question? What you call shadow is the overlapping faces, you need to avoid overlapping faces

Comment: That's called z-fighting. It's where two faces overlap exactly and Blender can't tell which one to display "on top".